# Python 2.7.x setup on Windows 7?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

Never setup Python on Windows 7 before (use Python on Mac and Linux in the past). Wondering any guide to setup Python 2.7.x and packages (I use pandas, numpy, etc.) on Windows?

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Anaconda may fill your bill, it's fairly easy to set up  on Windows and comes with pandas, numpy, and many other scientific and numerical packages.https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: @paisanco, vote up. And how about for Python itself?

Comment: pip works on windows, as well as virtualenv. A quick google lands this guide: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/, then us pip and virtualenv like normal.

Comment: @MyCah, thanks, and vote up. what is virtualenv? I think pip is good enough for installing packages?

Comment: @LinMa Virtualenv allows you to install packages at a project level, not globally. Then you do not have to install packages for your global Python install, which could cause dependency issues. It's highly recommended to use a virtualenv for every single project you work on. It makes things much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few of options:

- Use Anaconda. (https://www.continuum.io/downloads)
- Use Python from https://www.python.org/downloads/ and install binaries of other libraries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
- Use Active state python (http://www.activestate.com/activepython and http://www.activestate.com/activepython/python-financial-scientific-modules)

Comment: Thanks okkhoy, vote up. For Anaconda, could I use it with PyCharm on Windows?

Comment: Should be possible, though I have not really tried. I believe PyCharm automatically detects the python installation and uses it. If not, you can manually point PyCharm to use Anaconda python

Comment: Thanks okkhoy, vote up. What do you mean "point PyCharm to use Anaconda python"? Do you mean point interpreter?

Comment: In the PyCharm settings, you can set the interpreter to Anaconda python.

Comment: Thanks okkhoy, how to verify Anaconda could be installed correctly?

Comment: Thanks for all the help okkhoy, mark your reply as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check for python(X,Y)

http://python-xy.github.io/

This is available for only python 2.7.X - latest is 2.7.10. 
With the installations you get many necessary libraries like numpy, Pandas, PIL, openpyxl, pip etc..

Comment: Thanks panchal0905, vote up. :) How it compares to Anaconda?

Comment: Anaconda is available for Windows , Linux and os X where as python(X,Y) is only for Windows. Both have Spyder IDE which I think is excellent for writing code. It autocompletes the class names with TAB and also suggests the error or warning messages while writing the code.

I think both are good but this also will depend on the application you want to develope. I found my requirements enough with Python(x,y) so I did not gave much efforts for Anaconda.